# cakephp: how can i display a default value in my dropdownlist?

Tags: php, cakephp

i want to display a default value like 'select category' insted of blanck space

*here is my tables*

**category_tbls**

- `id`
- `cat_name`

**subcategory_tbls**

- `id`
- `category_tbls_id`
- `sub_cat`

*Model*
**Addcat.php**

```
class Addcat extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'category_tbls';
    public $hashMany = 'subcategory_tbls';
}
```

*Model*
**Subcat.php**

```
class Subcat extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'subcategory_tbls';
    public $belongsTo = 'category_tbls';
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
public function subcat()
{
    $this->loadModel("Subcat");

    if($this->Subcat->save($this->request->data))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Successully save your information!');
    }

    $this->loadModel("Addcat");
    $dt=$this->Addcat->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','cat_name')));
    $this->set('drop',$dt);
```

view file is as bellow

**subcat.ctp**

```
<h2>Add Sub Category!</h2>
                    <form action="subcat" method="post">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->select('category_tbls_id',$drop);?>
                        <input type="text" name="sub_cat" placeholder="sub category name" required/>

                        <button type="submit" class="b1">Add Sub Category</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `3rd parameter` in your select function. If you don't want to show `empty` value in your `dropdown`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('category_tbls_id',$drop,array('empty' => 'Select Category'));?>
```

Comment: working but it's showing my 1st category as default in dropdown not text like 'select category'

Comment: I have set `empty` value in my code. Give it try with it.